# how to handle a :reject_if if a new record and not an update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am working on some forms that involve uploading an image. There is a standard two forms to add and all the forms currently associated. It will look like this:

[image]

I have an assets class that is polymorphic for other classes involved (such as locations, items). The problem is that items can be uploaded or updated. For items and locations, I have the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:asset].blank? }
```

but this seems to reject if there is no uploaded file. This is essentially what we want if it is a new file but there are cases where we just update the description via the asset id. The above :reject_if will reject that scenario. How can I make an exception for updating this other type of information?

thx

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding a condition on `params[:id]` to the `reject_if` block.  For your example, it would look like this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true, 
    :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:asset].blank? && a[:id].blank? }
```

Any existing records should come back with an `id` attribute in the nested hash, so this should allow updates to existing nested records while still allowing you to reject new records with no `asset` (because new records don't yet have an `id`).